# How to override node content in Twig

Tags: theming

I have created no of nodes as content type as Article in my website(techladder.in). But I am not getting the right file where I can override the content of the file.

For example, I need to display author information above the Disqus comment section.

I was able to override the node file in my theme at following path:
theme/templates/content/node--article.html.twig as following:

```
     {%   set classes = [
        'node',
        'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
        node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
        node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
        not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
        view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,   ] %} {{ attach_library('classy/node') }} <article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>

      {{ title_prefix }}   {% if not page %}
        <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
          <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
        </h2>   {% endif %}   {{ title_suffix }}

      {% if display_submitted %}
        <footer class="comment-submitted">
          <div{{ author_attributes.addClass('node__submitted') }}>
            {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
            {{ metadata }}
          </div>
        </footer>   {% endif %}

      <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content') }}>
        {{ content }}   </div>

    </article> 
{% if teaser %} <div class="section-divider"><hr class="section-divider"></div> {% endif %}
```

But here, I am not able to find a file where I can override the `content` of the node.

Does anyone has suggestions how can I do it in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`content` is just the render array composed of renderable elements.

If you want to break up the fields, then you need to not use `{{ content }}` and instead call each field where you want them:

`{{ content.field_MYFIELD }}`

Those fields are controlled by their field templates.

An improvement on your code would be to not check for view modes in one template, but just make each view mode a template like `node--article--teaser.html.twig`, `node--article--full.html.twig`, `node--article--some-other-mode.html.twig`. It will make your code cleaner.

So you'll need to debug and find what the `content` variable has, and just start outputting it where you want them to render in the template.

Comment: Thanks! It is helpful. When I am trying to render {{ content.field_CATEGORY}} it is not displaying anything on the screen. I think field_CATEGORY is not correct. Could you correct me here?

Comment: You'll have to find the machine name in the backend or use a debugger to see what they are. Aside from that, fields need to be VISIBLE under "Manage Display" and not hidden - then they are included in the content variable.